# load json query result to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

Complete the 'load_query_result_to_df' function to load the 'api_query_res' result from the
previous 'get_res_for_API_query' to a dataframe.
Use the api_query_res.json() to get a dictionary (representing the json), as explained above.

```
def get_res_for_API_query(included_field_value_pairs, excluded_field_value_pairs):
   u="http://moocdsand.ml:8080/api/records/1.0/search?dataset=chocolate-bars"
  
   if excluded_field_value_pairs:
       for key, value in excluded_field_value_pairs:
           u+="&exclude." + key + "=" + value
          
   if included_field_value_pairs:
       for key in range(0 , len(included_field_value_pairs)):
           u+=  "&refine." + included_field_value_pairs[key][0] + "=" + included_field_value_pairs[key][1]
   response = requests.get(u)
   return response
```

**the function that isn't working :**

```
def load_query_result_to_df(api_query_res):  
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(api_query_res.json(), orient='index')
   return df
```

I getting the this errors :

KeyError: 'cocoa_percent'
AssertionError: Wrong number of results for query

Answer (score 0):

You could try something a little simpler like:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(results, record_path = ['results'])
```

This will flatten the result and produce a new dataframe named df.

It may be easier to handle the data once it has been imported into the dataframe.

Comment: `def load_query_result_to_df(api_query_res):  
    results=None
    #names=["compony","name","review_date","cocoa_percent","company_location","rating","broad_bean_origin","bean_type"]
    r=api_query_res.json()
    for i in range(len(r["records"])):
        row=pd.json_normalize(r["fields"][i])
        if results is None:
            results= row
        else:
            results.append(row)
    df = pd.json_normalize(results, record_path = ['records'])
    return df`

Comment: {"nhits": 2, "parameters": {"dataset": "chocolate-bars", "refine": {"company": "Acalli"}, "timezone": "UTC", "rows": 10, "format": "json"}, "records": [{"datasetid": "chocolate-bars", "recordid": "8f51...b42c", "fields": {"rating": 3.75, "review_date": "2015", "name": "Tumbes, Norandino", "cocoa_percent": 70, "company": "Acalli", "bean_type": "Criollo", "company_location": "U.S.A.", "broad_bean_origin": "Peru", "ref": "1470"}, "record_timestamp": "2016-12-20T16:57:04.946000+00:00"}, {"datasetid": "chocolate-bars", "recordid": "685b...81d8", "fields": {"rating": 3.75, "review_date": "2015", ...

Comment: ***i need to get the fields***